# CMake and clang_complete

Tags: cmake, clang-complete

I'm wanting to setup my CMakeLists.txt file so that it can generate the .clang_complete file required by the vim plugin clang_complete.

Ordinarily, you would do this by passing a parameter to the python script it supplies with the compiler and all of the parameters for compilation. Note that I am omitting the actual directory cc_args.py is in to save on space.

```
cc_args.py gcc test.c -o test -I~/IncludeDirs/
```

You can also do this during the make phase...

```
make CC='cc_args.py gcc' CXX='cc_args.py g++'
```

However, I am unsure of how to (if it is possible to) set this up within a CMakeLists.txt file. It's really annoying to have to type this in every time I want to setup clang_complete. The reason why I want to do it this way, is because I have multiple projects that I use a custom script to build the CMakeLists.txt file, so having to write a script for each one or manually place a generic one is a step I'd like to avoid.

I've tried a couple of things that have so far have come up with errors.

I've tried setting CMAKE_CC_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to lines similar to the first i.e. "cc_args.py g++". The errors that come up here say that It can't find the compiler (which is understandable).

The next thing I tried was setting the Compiler variables just to the cc_args.py and adding a flag for the actual compiler: suffice to say, that failed horribly. CMake said that it couldn't compile a test program (considering the script isn't a compiler, and the tests don't use the flags I set, I'm not surprised at this).

So without writing any other external scripts that require moving around, is there anyone that can think of a way that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said "without writing any other external scripts," but it seems like you just need a one-liner:

```
exec cc_args.py g++
```

And then set that file as your CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER.  You could even use CMake's `file()` function to write the one-liner at build time if you don't want to have to distribute it.

Comment: Hmm... I'll give it a shot and see what I can do. I had no idea the file() function existed, so that may solve my problem.

Comment: Using `file()` would work, but you'd have to do it before calling `project()` and set your `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_INIT` variable to point to it. You can't change the compiler once it's been set in CMake.

Comment: Ah, that would explain another problem I've been having with the Compilers. I had an option to set the compiler, that wouldn't actually change the compiler.

Comment: Using the file function did the trick for me, however I had to change the permissions using the cmake execute_process and chmod to make it executable... Not the most ideal way, but it does the job. I also had to add $@ to pass all the arguments through to the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to set the CXX environment variable before executing cmake. Something like that:

```
CXX="$HOME/.vim/bin/cc_args.py clang++" cmake ..
make
```

See http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2013/01/29/vim-creating-clang_complete-using-cmake/ for more details.

Comment: I tried this approach, but it does not generate any `.clang_complete` file